# Tornado: how to launch asynchronous threads

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, tornado

I'm following the Tornado tutorial here: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/locks.html#tornado.locks.Condition

Now instead of one waiter, I want two threads waiting for the same condition variable. When the condition is released, I want the threads to start doing work *asynchronously*.

Here's my attempt to do this:

```py
from time import sleep
from tornado import gen
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.locks import Condition

condition = Condition()

@gen.coroutine
def waiter():
    print('1: waiting')
    yield condition.wait()  # Yield a Future.
    print('1: finish waiting')
    for i in range(5):
        sleep(1)
        print('1: doing work', i)

@gen.coroutine
def waiter2():
    print('2: waiting')
    yield condition.wait()  # Yield a Future.
    print('2: finish waiting')
    for i in range(5):
        sleep(1)
        print('2: doing work', i)

@gen.coroutine
def notifier():
    print("About to notify")
    sleep(2)
    condition.notify_all()
    print("Done notifying")

@gen.coroutine
def runner():
    # combines the futures
    yield [waiter(), waiter2(), notifier()]

IOLoop.current().run_sync(runner)
```

However, waiter2 always wakes up and starts doing work *after* waiter1 exits.

I have also attempted to call `IOLoop.current().run_sync()` twice, but Tornado throws `RuntimeError: IOLoop has already started.`

Could anyone please show me what's the correct code to launch threads asynchronously? Thanks!

**EDIT**

The answer points out that `sleep` should be replaced by `gen.sleep`. This is completely correct for the code snippet I posted, so thank you for that.

However, the `sleep()` here is only for illustration purpose. What I really want is `waiter()` and `waiter2()` doing long-running blocking processing *simultaneously*. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call `time.sleep` in your code because such a long blocking call interferes fundamentally with the way tornado's `IOLoop` works. Replace your calls to `time.sleep` with the `tornado.gen.sleep` coroutine and your code works just fine:

```
from time import sleep
from tornado import gen
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.locks import Condition

condition = Condition()

@gen.coroutine
def waiter():
    print('1: waiting')
    yield condition.wait()  # Yield a Future.
    print('1: finish waiting')
    for i in range(5):
        yield gen.sleep(1)
        print('1: doing work', i)

@gen.coroutine
def waiter2():
    print('2: waiting')
    yield condition.wait()  # Yield a Future.
    print('2: finish waiting')
    for i in range(5):
        yield gen.sleep(1)
        print('2: doing work', i)

@gen.coroutine
def notifier():
    print("About to notify")
    yield gen.sleep(2)
    condition.notify_all()
    print("Done notifying")

@gen.coroutine
def runner():
    # combines the futures
    yield [waiter(), waiter2(), notifier()]

IOLoop.current().run_sync(runner)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Quick followup: what if the blocker is not `sleep`, but a computationally intensive function `long_math()`? How can I have the two waiters do the calculation asynchronously?

Comment: It is not possible for two Python functions to do computation at once, because of the GIL.